# iOS- How to capture color negative from camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, custom-controls

I am new in iOS. I want to create custom camera app by which I can capture color negative image from camera and save it in custom folder.

I've searched and tried myself but could not find anything helpful. Please share just a demo project or a link. I am able to capture normal image and save it in album, but I need to capture a color negative image from camera. Any suggestion will be great.

Thank you guys.

Comment: **@ Lagomorph, First point I need code iOS not for Java, and second thing is : I don't want convert , I want capture (dynamic) image from camera, Means user must able to see color negative image in camera at run time. Thanks**

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Post your code here and point out where you are having issue.

Answer (score 2):

@monu please check this link. May be its help to you https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [GpuImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) which is a great library for applying Gpu-accelerated filters to live camera feed.

I think it has a premade ColorInvert filter. Also you can write your own filters using shaders which is more advanced.

The other way is to use **AvFoundation** and get camera feed with **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput**, convert captured frames in CIImage and then use Core Image FIlters(**CIColorInvert**).